# Writing to textboxes from textfiles on vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I made a textfile with a Customer Name and Phone Number and im trying to insert these details into different textboxes. Thanks

```
 Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    If (strOrderName <> "") And IO.File.Exists("Order#1.txt") Then
        Dim query = From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines("Order#1.txt")
        Let name = line.Split(","c)(0)
        Let phonenum = line.Split(","c)(1)
        Name = txtName.Text
        phonenum = txtPhoneNumber.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 3):

Your assignment statements are backwards.  Here you're putting the values of your textboxes into your variables:

```
name = txtName.Text
phonenum = txtPhoneNumber.Text
```

Instead, put the values of your variables into your textboxes:

```
txtName.Text = name
txtPhoneNumber.Text = phonenum
```

---

Additionally, you don't use [`Let`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/queries/let-clause) to declare a local variable.  Use [`Dim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement) for that.  (Just like you already do for your first variable.)

```
Dim name = line.Split(","c)(0)
Dim phonenum = line.Split(","c)(1)
```

---

Also, what is this supposed to do?:

```
Dim query = From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines("Order#1.txt")
```

If you want all the lines, then just read all the lines:

```
Dim query = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Order#1.txt")
```

Then which line are you going to use for your values?  The first one?:

```
Dim name = query(0).Split(","c)(0)
Dim phonenum = query(0).Split(","c)(1)
```

Overall it looks like you're getting confused in an attempt to use LINQ keywords where they don't really apply.  All you're trying to do here is read two values from your file.  You can perhaps use LINQ to query the lines of the file to find a specific line, but the question doesn't really indicate that.  It looks like you just need to read your file, decide which line of data to use (above I'm defaulting to the first line, and assuming there is at least one line), and use the values from that line.

(Assuming your file has multiple lines, etc.  I don't know your file structure, only the code you're showing and how it reads that structure.)

Comment: Hi David , That didn't seem to work as name and phonenum aren't declared as variables.When I try to declare them as variables it is upsetting the 'Let' function. Thanks Again

Comment: @PadraigOSullivan: What is `Let`?  In VB I've only ever used `Dim` to declare a variable.  Which you're also using, so I just assumed `Let` was something I wasn't familiar with.  When you say "it is upsetting" what specifically do you mean?  Is there an error?  An unexpected result?  Be specific about the problem.  "It is upsetting" isn't something we can really help with.

Comment: There is a let clause in a LINQ expression, or Let/Get in VB6/VBA for a property, FWIW.